# Control key seems virtually stuck

Tags: 18.04

I have a new xps developer edition laptop, so it shipped with Ubuntu 18.04. At first I couldn't figure out why it was drawing rectangles whenever I would move the cursor. Nothing is hitting either control key, they are not physically stuck and like I mentioned, it's brand new. I have tried hitting various keys, the super key works to get me 'out' -sort-of, I can click another window, and it will unstick momentarily but then start dragging whatever is in the path of the moving cursor again. I've also tried the Alt keys, Ctrl (on either side) and the keys across the top, which don't give what you would expect (they don't give anything) when this starts. I have even done a reinstall from scratch and this issue has stayed. I got this laptop to learn linux better, but I am a bit frustrated by now. (READ: Please speak slowly, using small words. :) )
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you plug in an external USB keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've been waiting for it to repeat to find out. In truth, I am not sure how to get it to repeat. I am suspecting virtualbox, but honestly am not sure.